Do lookalike characters in question titles pose any risks?
Attacks via "lookalike domains" are a known malicious trick.  Is any risk posed by a lookalike question title?
I know that's rather vague, and it's a concern that seldom arises.  I give an example, but my question is not specifically about the example.
Today's question Generał equation for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2-(f(x+it)+f(x-it))}{e^{2 \pi t}-1}dt$ is only the second time I've seen it—which, as the saying goes, isn't a lot, but it's weird that it happened twice.  (Unfortunately, I've forgotten what the first occurrence was.)  The accidental substitution of ł for l seems unlikely, and its occurrence in the first post by a new user makes me suspicious, but, on the other hand, I can't see what harm it can do.
Again, without focusing on this particular example (unless it is relevant to the answer), can any more suspicious-minded MathOverflowian help me see the threat that something like this could pose (in which case the post should be flagged for moderator attention), or should I just edit it (as I did in this case) and move on?

Why does it seem that unlikely to you? What if the user is Polish?

@ToddTrimble, re, good point. Actually I didn't know the common Polish layout put those two characters together. Anyway, I didn't intend to single out this post, just to give it as the only motivating example I had handy. If you think it detracts from the question or inappropriately singles out the example post, then I have no objection to removing it.

The only attack I'm thinking of using lookalike titles is to bypass some kind of automated moderation (like a spam filter) - there just isn't much other reason for a computer to be processing text in titles in enough detail for anything interesting to happen. And if that does happen, well, we have human moderators. I guess it could also mess up search results, but I wouldn't expect anything particularly important to depend on search working exactly correctly, so it's still pretty unclear what the threat would be.

Actually: messing up search could be a way to evade moderation. Questions that are obviously low-quality will get noticed anyway, and there isn't an obvious motivation to secretly post duplicate questions; so it would have to be something more complicated, where each question looks fine in isolation, but looking at all of them together would (for instance) reveal that one person with several accounts is trying to use MO to cheat on a test.

But I also agree that, in reality, it just being a mistake of some kind seems more likely than this very specific complicated plot. And if for some reason we are worried about this threat that I just made up, then writing a generalised tool to find lookalike titles seems more productive than flagging individual questions.

@LSpice It's fine to ask, and I appreciate your alertness. But I think this particular instance is unproblematic, a careless error. Thanks for editing.

FWIW, “generał” is the Polish word for “general (military rank)”. So apart from a typo, it could also be the result of browser autocorrection.

This is not exactly the same thing, but I remember once seeing a question where someone put "[closed]" in the title, I think just to mess around and see what would happen. I could've sworn there was a meta question about this incidence, but I can't find it now...
